# why the monodromy representation of the local system $\Bbb{Z}_M$ is trivial?

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

Let $M$ be some connected topological space, assume it has the local system $\Bbb{Z}_M$ then we can associate a monodromy representation $\rho: \pi_1(M,x) \to \text{Aut}(\Bbb{Z})$.

Why this representation is trivial? I know isomorphism between $\Bbb{Z}$ should be $\text{Id},-\text{Id}$ it has two elements why it's trivial?

---

The question coming from this wonderful article by Fouad EI Zein and Jawad Snoussi linked in the comment. The theorem goes as follows:

> **Corollary 1.9.** The group of global sections of the local system $\mathcal{L}$ is isomorphic to the invariant subspace of the fiber $L$
> at the reference point $v$ under the action of the representation
> $\rho$ ( where $\rho$ is the monodromy representation of $\mathcal{L}$
> here) $$ H^0(M, \mathcal{L}) \simeq L^\rho:=\left\{a \in L \mid
>  \rho(\alpha)(a)=a, \forall \alpha \in \pi_1(M, v)\right\} $$

**Proof.**

(Step 1) Applied the equivalence between the local system and representation of fundamental group $\pi_1(M,v)$ to the constant sheaf $\mathbb{Z}_M$.

States that the space of morphisms $\varphi \in \operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}, \mathcal{L})$ is isomorphic to the space of morphisms of the trivial representation $\mathbb{Z}$ into $\rho$.

(Step 2) On one side $\operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}, \mathcal{L})$ is isomorphic to the space of global section $H^0(M, \mathcal{L})$

(Step 3) On the other side the morphisms from the trivial representation $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathcal{L}$ are defined by elements $a \in L$ satisfying the above formula where $\rho(\alpha)=I d$ since it is the image by $\varphi$ of the trivial action on $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: There's no reason for it to be trivial. Why do you think it would be?

Comment: Oh thank you @Thorgott , I was reading a article by Fouad EI Zein and Jawad Snoussi, there is Corollary 1.9 use this fact (I will paste the proof in the post) :https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~fouad.elzein/elzein-snoussif.pdf

Comment: @Thorgott , I have figured out all the detail except Step 3. which needs to consider the morphism between monodromy representation of local system $\Bbb{Z}_M$ and $\mathcal{L}$, which should be the equivariant map between $\Bbb{Z}$ and $L$. If I can show the monodromy representation of $\Bbb{Z}$ is trivial then I can finish the proof

Comment: Ah, I see now. $\mathbb{Z}_M$ is not an arbitrary local system, it is the local system corresponding to the constant sheaf with value $\mathbb{Z}$. The monodromy representation of this specific local system is indeed tirival. I suggest you work this out carefully.

Comment: Oh thank you so much Thorgott ,I got it, we can choose this first from the representation of the fundamental group side which is a trivial representation, then go back to local system side which is the constant sheaf over $\Bbb{Z}$, in step two ,we use the adjointness $\text{Hom}_{\underline{\Bbb{Z}}_X}(\underline{\Bbb{Z}}_X, \mathcal{L}) \cong \text{Hom}_{\Bbb{Z}}(\Bbb{Z},\Gamma(M,\mathcal{L})) \cong\Gamma(M,\mathcal{L}) $, it's easier to distinguish local system from the representaion of the fundamental group side